# MongoEngine import problems - Python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I'm using `pymongo` and `mongoengine`.
When I do

```
import mongoengine
```

In my `/home/ubuntu/project` directory
I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> import mongoengine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import document
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 17, in <module>
    import collections
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
ImportError: cannot import name iskeyword
```

In other directories I am able to run the `import` command, but not in my project directory. For example, in `/home/ubuntu/` I'm getting:

```
>>> import mongoengine
>>>
```

Any clues?

### ****** Edit ******

There seems to be some confusion: both `pymongo` and `mongoengine` are installed using `pip`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>> import mongoengine
>>>
```

Comment: Have you installed pymongo from the source.. It seems like you have not installed it to the default python path. Try installing using following commands 'pip install pymongo'

Comment: @vdkotian I did installed using `pip`

Comment: please just ref to this documentation http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/installing.html . Make sure you have mongodb at accessible location.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pymongo or mongoengine is not included in your default python path.

Try installing with following command

```
pip install pymongo
pip install mongoengine
```

[Source](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.2/installation.html) For the installation documentation and further details.
[Source for mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/installing.html) Documentation.